# How do i continuously play a generated sound in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Suppose i have a function which generates a continuous stream of audio samples. How do i get it CONTINUOUSLY played in browser in a more or less universally supported way? Examples of WebAudio API involve playing pieces one by one which, in the case it is a human voice for example, make it jerky.

Can be easily done with MediaSource API, but it's not supported on iPhones...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `setTimeout` loop using recursion:

```
function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Do Something Here
        // create a recursive loop.
        timeout();
    }, 1000);
}
```

in it you have to provide media playtime and when the user is changing the media to different media use `clearTimeout` function